# Одержувач чи отримувач?

Tags: вибір-слова

Чи можна вживати в українській мові слова "одержувач" та "отримувач" і чи є між ними якась різниця?
Перше слово, "одержувач", знаходимо у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/oderzhuvach), отож можна зробити висновок, що його можна вживати. Однак, як бути із словом "отримувач" - у СУМі його немає_ однак знаходимо його як [термін](https://www.bitlex.ua/uk/blog/terms/post/otrymuvach) пов'язаний із банківською тематикою(особа, на рахунок якої зараховується сума переказу або яка отримує суму переказу у готівковій формі), а також на [порталі української мови](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%CE%D2%D0%C8%CC%D3%C2%C0%D7), де воно має те саме значення, що і "одержувач" (Особа, яка отримує що-небудь). Крім того, бачимо це слово у онлайн-словнику [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/uk/en/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87).

Отож, чи є ці слова синонімами і чи справді можна вживати слово "отримувач"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оскільки СУМ дає визначення дериватів як синонімів одержувати-отримувати, то і похідні слова можна вважати повними синонімами.

[ОТРИ́МУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/otrymuvaty), ую, уєш, недок., ОТРИ́МАТИ, аю, аєш, док., перех. Те саме, що одержувати.

Answer (score -6):

Корінь слова Одержувати = ДЕРЖ (Держати). Держать-Російське слово
Корінь слова Отримувати = Трим (Тримати). Тримати -Українське слово
Чому слово Одержувати вважають Українським словом незрозуміло!?

Comment: Добрий день, пані Вікторіє, на цьому форумі заохочуються відповіді зі вказанням джерел, відповіді, засновані на власній думці, на цьому форумі вважаються за коментарі, а тому мінусуються або видаляються. Будьте ласкаві, подивіться в етимолоґчному словнику походження кореня "держ", і якщо воно справді походить з російської, а не з якоїсь давнішої мови Русі, то додайте цитату зі словника, яка б це підтверджувала. Ось посилання на словник: http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm

Comment: А як щодо слова держава?

Comment: @Yola тримава /ж